# Well - Water - Plumbing, Setup advice

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, well, well-pump, water-softener

We have a well system in our home, which is multi-story (*basement and 2 floors*),  and I am looking to optimize the setup of the system to make it more efficient. As you can tell from the photo whoever plumbed it did some weird things.
The system includes a well tank (*blue*), holding tank (*gray*), water softener (*tan*), 50-micron filter, and 20-micron filter (*black/blue*).

Some issues we have run into is water pressure when multiple items run. (*I.E. Faucet and (top load) washer or shower with faucet and toilet going*) These are intermittent issues and we have learned somewhat to stagger usage to overcome this. Another issue it seems we have is, not having enough water in the well tank and/or holding tank to  adequately supply the home when trying to use 2 washing machines, people in different showers at one time, water the garden/plants (*I.E. Long water run time*). Also, I have a noticeable dip in PSI from my well, at 70 PSI, to my holding tank, at about 55-60 PSI. From the well to the holding tank it only passes through a 50-micron filter which is cleaned   every 2 weeks, minimum.

With all of that said, I am hoping someone can suggest a more efficient and compact setup of the well system that will also resolve the shortage of water too. The system currently goes left to right well tank (*blue*), 50-micron filter, holding tank (*gray*), 20-micron filter (*black/blue*), water softener (*tan*) then to supply the house. I am not sure what size any of the tanks are or how many gallons they hold. Also on the setup if someone could recommend a chlorinator or UV sanitizer that would be awesome!

Our well is 600 feet deep in the backyard.

[image]

Comment: I think I'd be looking at your two filters and check their specifications as compared to your water flow needs.

Comment: Is your irrigation/plants watering running through the filtration system? There is no need to do so, plants can be watered directly from the well. Pressure isn't the only consideration, water system testers also test flow volume (had this done before installing sprinkler system to make sure I had good supply)

Comment: "supply the home when trying to use 2 washing machines, people in different showers at one time, water the garden/plants" All at once? You're probably not going to be happy trying to do that on a city water supply, let alone well water!

Comment: "*supply the home when trying to use 2 washing machines, people in different showers at one time, water the garden/plants*" It seams like the first place to start is a **Much bigger** pressure tank.

Comment: @FredricShope All water runs through the filtration system. This is how it was originally set up but my future state would have a manifold to split the outside faucets so they would not be filtered.

Comment: @FreeMan down here in we had consistent 80 PSI off a faucet. (Yes I know that high is hard on things but we never had a problem in 12 years.) It's a big difference going from 80 to 60 and we are adjusting.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I don't know a lot about wells but it seems a larger pressure tank could help but I would still continue to have an issue with the volume of water used either 2 showers, 2 washers, etc. I would think I need some sort of storage tank to hold more water 300 Gal. and the well could fill the big tank. I just don't know how to get from what I have to a 300 Gal. holding tank.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to answer your questions about your domestic water supply, more information is necessary, such as the well's volume capacity and the pumps pumping capacity or to put it another way, "how much water volume do you have? If you know or can find out who drilled the well he may be able to tell you the wells capacity and the size of the installed pump. If you can't find out that information, you can proceed by simply assuming  that the well has never gone dry or ran out of pumping water. I would recommend that you have the water tested for everything and identify what each device  installed in the water line does to see if every device is actually needed. Each device has a certain amount of pressure loss and eliminating even one device may improve the water supply. For example, if there is no sediment in the water why is there a filter (blue black) installed and if there is you should probably change that filter to one with a larger flow rate or pipe 2 or 3 in parallel. What does that grey tank with the pressure gauge near the top do? Is it a filter of some kind, what is it's purpose, and do you need it. Do you need the water softner? If your water is "hard" you probably need it and if it is not it could be eliminated. Most wells have hard water. -

Next, I would do the following;  #1) Assume that the blue well water storage tank is too small and install at least one or more, 119 gallon pressurized well tank tank available at most most home improvement stores. #2) Re-pipe the supply pipe if possible, from the well head to the storage tank or tanks with the largest diameter piping available and from the pressurized tank or tanks to the hot water tank with 1" copper equivalent.  Make sure that all supply piping to the house is done with at least 3/4" copper equivalent piping using no 1/2" tees. Only use reducing tees like 3/4"x3/4"x1/2" no 1/2"x1/2"x1/2" tees. When adding any shut-off valve make sure that you only use a "full port" valve to reduce the valves restriction. Also, a good "water test" will help determine if you really need a chlorinator or UV sanitizer. Unless you are in a water table or aquifer with bad water I doubt that those devices are needed. Water from 600' below ground is usually pretty good water. One last thing, You will almost always have a water line pressure drop when filling a clothes washer since they usually do not have any restrictive device in their supply line. Having a larger supply line and an adequate well tank capacity will lessen the pressure drop.

Hope this helps.